# Can closed balls also be a neighborhood basis?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am reading about bases in topology and have encountered the concept of a (local) neighborhood basis. The example they give is for the topology on metric spaces: the set of all open balls around $x$ (or the set of all small open balls around $x$, or all open balls with radius $\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ around $x$). What confuses me is why they only give open balls as examples. Would the set of all closed balls around $x$ also be an example of a neighborhood basis? I think that it satisfies the definition, but I can't find any source mentioning it as an example.

---

**Edit:** (adding the definition)

A *neighbourhood system* $\mathcal{N}(x)$ for a point $x$ is the collection of all neighbourhoods of the point $x$.

A *neighbourhood basis* or *local basis* for a point $x$ is a subset $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{N}(x)$, such that for all $V \in \mathcal{N}(x)$, there exists some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B \subseteq V$. That is, for every neighbourhood $V$, we can find a neighbourhood $B$ in the neihbourhood basis that is contained in $V$.

---

**Edit 2:** (definition of neighbourhood)

If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a topological space and $x$ is a point in $X$, a neighbourhood of $x$ is any set $U \in \mathcal{T}$ containing $x$.

Comment: Please include the definition of "neighborhood basis" you are using.

Comment: @coffeemath done!

Comment: You are not quite done, you forgot to define what you mean by a *neighborhood*. There are two nonequivalent definitions in the literature (going back to Bourbaki and Kelly) and it is critical which one you use.

Comment: @MoisheKohan done!

Comment: @MoisheKohan ok, i think i just realised, rewriting the definition of a neighbourhood, that the answer is no, since neighbourhood are elements of $\mathcal{T}$ and are open

Comment: Matthew-- That's my answer also, once terms are defined. Note other texts/writers define things differently and answer would be yes for some of them.

Comment: @coffeemath I think this is why I was confused, because I initially thought neighbourhood doesn't have to be open (last year in real analysis we defined neighbourhoods in metric spaces as any set that contains $x$). But, this year in topology, we defined it differently.

Comment: Using the general definition of neighbourhood a space has a base of closed neighbourhoods iff it is regular, and metric spaces are regular and closed balls (for $r>0$) form a base of closed neighbourhoods. In the strict definition (neighbourhood is open) this is not the case necessarily.

Comment: With this clarification, I suggest, you write an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Matthew Your statement that "in real analysis we defined neighbourhoods in metric spaces as any set that contains $x$" is not right. For example the set $\{x\}$ contains the point $x$ (but no other point) and is not a neighborhood in any sense. In a metric space a neighborhood of a point $x$ must contain at least all points $y$ at some positive distance $k$ (where $d$ may depend on $x$) from $x$. That is there must be $k>0$ such that $d(x,y)<k$ implies $y$ is in the neighborhood. Other points may be in the neighborhood or not.

Comment: @coffeemath you are right, I checked my notes and it says that a neighbourhood of $x$ is any set that contains a ball with center at $x$ and positive radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no commonly accepted definition of the conecpt of a *neighborhood*.

Some authors define it as in your Edit 2. That is, a neigborhood of a point $x \in X$ is an open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $x \in U$.

Other authors define a neighborhood of $x \in X$ to be any subset $N \subset X$ such that there exists an open $ U \subset X$ with the property $x \in U \subset N$.

Clearly, the second variant is more general than the first. Using this variant, one must explicitly speak about *open neighorhoods* if one wants to refer to the neigborhoods in the sense of variant 1. But there also exist closed neigborhoods, compact neighborhoods etc.

Personally I prefer variant 2 because it is more flexible. And you need this interpretation to state that that in a metric space $X$ the set of all closed balls around $x$ form a neighborhood basis.

Let us write  $\mathcal N_1(x)$ for the neighbourhood system of $x$ in the sense of variant 1 and $\mathcal N_2(x)$ for that in the sense of variant 2. Clearly $\mathcal N_1(x) \subset \mathcal N_2(x)$, but in general $\mathcal N_1(x) \ne \mathcal N_2(x)$, i.e. $\mathcal N_1(x) $ is a *proper subset* of $\mathcal N_2(x)$.

Let us come to your question. Your interpretation of a neigborhood is that of variant 1. Since closed balls are in general no open sets, they do in general not belong to $\mathcal N_1(x)$, but only to $\mathcal N_2(x)$. Therefore in general they do not form a neighbourhood basis for the  point $x$ in the sense of Edits 1 and 2.

However, if you work with $\mathcal N_2(x)$, then the closed balls do form neighbourhood basis for $x$. See GEdgars answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, in a metric space you could use the closed balls (with positive radius) centered at a point $x$ as a neighborhood basis for $x$.  Then define: a set $E$ is **open** iff, for every $x \in E$ there exists an element $U$ of the neighborhood basis at $x$ so that $x \in U \subseteq E$.  Even if your neighborhood bases do not consist of open sets, you still get a topology by doing this.

To prove this works (using open balls or closed balls for the neighborhood basis give you the same topology):
The main thing you need is: every open ball centered at $x$ contains a closed ball centered at $x$, and every closed ball centered at $x$ contains an open ball centered at $x$.

Comment: The advantage of allowing neighborhoods here that are not open is that we can use such neighborhood bases to **define** a topology; when we set it up we do not know what **open sets** are, so we cannot limit the sets of the neighborhood bases to open sets.